# Residualizing in OLS

Tags: regression, least-squares, linear

Consider a linear regression

$$ y_i = A_i' \theta + B_i' \psi + \epsilon_i $$

There's a "trick" to find the parameters $\theta$  and $\psi$ in a stepwise fashion.

First minimizing squared error wrt. $\theta$:
$$\hat{\theta}(\psi) = (A^t A)^{-1} A^t (y - B\psi) $$

Plugging back in, the residuals are
$$ \epsilon = ( I - A(A^t A)^{-1} A^t ) (y - B \psi)$$
so the idea is that to find $\hat{\psi}$ by residualizing both $y$ and $B$ with respect to $A$.

Let $y_{\perp A} = (I - A(A^t A)^{-1} A^t) y $ and $B_{\perp A} = (I - A(A^t A)^{-1} A^t) B$.
Then you just do
$$ \hat{\psi} = (B_{\perp A}^t B_{\perp A})^{-1} B_{\perp A}^t y_{\perp A}$$

My questions are:

- What is this called? I've tried searching for "stepwise regression", but that's definitely not the right term
- Is it possible to extend this argument to a case when the dependence on $\psi$ is non-linear? I'm currently fitting the non-linear model to the residuals of the linear one, but I'm not sure if it's a valid thing to do

Many thanks

Comment: Is the [Frisch–Waugh–Lovell theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frisch%E2%80%93Waugh%E2%80%93Lovell_theorem) what are you looking for in (1)?